# Opening text file in assets of android giving NullPointerException

Tags: java, android, file-io, nullpointerexception

I have some files in sub folder of `assets`, like `/assets/abc/0.txt` or `/assets/abc/3.txt` I am using the following code.

```
AssetManager mngr = getAssets();
String[] index = null;
```

`String[] files = mngr.list("abc")`;

```
try {

        InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(getAssets().open(
                files[0]));
        BufferedReader buffreader = new BufferedReader(reader);
        int c = 0;

        if (reader != null) {
            String line;
            while ((line = buffreader.readLine()) != null) {
                index[c] = line;
                c++;
                System.out.println("Line number " + line);
            }
            reader.close();

        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

I don't know why this code is not working and giving me NullPointerException.
Kindly tell me if there is any problem in this code.

**Edit**
my logcat is

```
07-17 23:58:24.023: W/System.err(1135): java.lang.NullPointerException
07-17 23:58:24.023: W/System.err(1135):     at com.example.abc.Main.readFile(Main.java:141)
07-17 23:58:24.023: W/System.err(1135):     at com.example.abc.Main.displayContent(Main.java:55)
07-17 23:58:24.023: W/System.err(1135):     at com.example.abc.Main.onCreate(Main.java:36)
07-17 23:58:24.023: W/System.err(1135):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
07-17 23:58:24.033: W/System.err(1135):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
07-17 23:58:24.033: W/System.err(1135):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
07-17 23:58:24.033: W/System.err(1135):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
07-17 23:58:24.033: W/System.err(1135):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
07-17 23:58:24.033: W/System.err(1135):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-17 23:58:24.033: W/System.err(1135):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
07-17 23:58:24.033: W/System.err(1135):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
07-17 23:58:24.033: W/System.err(1135):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-17 23:58:24.033: W/System.err(1135):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
07-17 23:58:24.033: W/System.err(1135):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
07-17 23:58:24.033: W/System.err(1135):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
07-17 23:58:24.033: W/System.err(1135):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Can you please post the logcat?

Comment: On which line you get the exception?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`String[] index = null;` is the source of error

`index[c] = line;` is where the nullPointerException happens;

you have to assingn an object to an array before you use it.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't assign anything other than null to variable index, then index[c] would at least cause null pointer exception.